# What does a positive value for command.Parameters.IsDirty indicate?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to get some value in output parameters using SqlCommand Parameters.

The stored procedure runs fine, giving proper records. I verified it executing procedure on Sql Server as well to be sure I am doing it right.

Still, I'm not able to get output on server-side, it always comes nothing! While debugging, I see that **IsDirty** proeprty for command.Parameters is set to True.

Can anyone tell what does it indicate?

Here is some code :

```
command.Parameters.Add("@count", SqlDbType.Int).Value = initialCountValue
command.Parameters("@count").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

Dim dr = command.ExecuteReader()

newCountValue = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters("@count").Value)
```

Here is procedure example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_some_procedure]

    @filter     INT
    @count      INT     output

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE         @filtered_ids TABLE(row_num INT IDENTITY(1,1), id INT primary key)
    INSERT INTO     @filtered_ids ( id )
    SELECT          id
    FROM            dbo.some_table
    WHERE           @filter = 0 OR table_field = @filter                
    ORDER BY        id desc

    SELECT  @count = COUNT(*)
    FROM    @filtered_ids 

    SELECT  some_table.*
    FROM    some_table
    INNER   JOIN @filtered_ids
    ON  some_table.id = @filtered_ids.id

END
```

Comment: please show your code . How do you declare your output params in your sql command ?

Comment: Also please show the SQL code of stored proc.

Comment: Try `ParameterDirection.InputOutput` instead.

Comment: No luck! Changing ParameterDirection did not work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output parameters are not visible to the calling code while the reader is opened.

Close the reader that you opened with `ExecuteReader`, then read your value:

```
Using dr = command.ExecuteReader()
   ...
End Using

newCountValue = CInt(command.Parameters("@count").Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) is an instance of [SqlParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx).  SqlParameterCollection does not have a publicly available member called IsDirty.  If you are seeing one in your `command.Parameters` then it is not an instance of `SqlParameterCollection` which means that `command` isn't an instance of `SqlCommand`.

I did find [what appears to be a decompiled version of the SqlParameterCollection class](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameterCollection@cs/1305376/SqlParameterCollection@cs) that seems to have an `internal` member called `IsDirty`, but you should not have access to this.

It seems to me that you are doing something weird here and it's entirely possible that is the cause of your problem.  I would add the default System.Data.SqlClient namespace and see if that resolves your problem.

It might help to post more of your code including where you are getting your SqlCommand class from.